# Nginx Reverse proxy not redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: apache, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

So i have a Nginx server working as a reverse proxy with this configuration

```
http {
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.tdl;
    access_log logs/reverse-access.log;
    error_log logs/reverse-error.log;

        location / {
                    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:443;
        }
    }

}
```

My only problem is that when i connect to example.tdl it redirects correctly, but not with HTTPS. But its redirecting to the https port of my Apache server so i dont know where is the problem.
I never used nginx before so this is probably a configuration error.

How can i make that nginx redirects to that port with https?

Answer (score 1):

This may sound dumb but what you've got is that `nginx` is working as a proxy for you. You connect to `nginx` via HTTP, `nginx` forwards your request to `apache` via HTTPS, then gets the answer back and transmit it to you using HTTP.

You need to make `nginx` listen for HTTPS with `listen 443 ssl;` and supply it with a certificate (`ssl_certificate <path>;`) and a key (`ssl_certificate_key <path>;`). After that add the following piece of code to the server block:

```
if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

This will redirect everything to HTTPS.